# How does 味 (taste, flavor) semantically appertain to 意味 (meaning)?

Tags: etymology

意味 baffles me. What the heck is 味 doing in 意味? What does 味 contribute or relate to 意味?

[image]

*Oxford Chinese Dictionary* (2010) p 892.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"taste" is a metaphor for "feeling"

"sweet" implies "happy"

"bitter" implies "resent"

"fishy/ rotten" implies "fear/disgust" --> suspicious

- 意(imply) 味(taste)
- 意味: imply; implication (you can feel/taste what it is)

Example:

The birth of the iPhone **implicated** the end of the iPod is near

iPhone 的诞生**意味**了 iPod 的末日已近

Answer (score 0):

My dictionary says 味 has the meaning of "smack", in English:

- have an element suggestive (of something), and
- a trace, touch, or suggestion of something.

So, combined with "意" - 意味 = the meaning suggests....